# Equation of a plane perpendicular to each of the two planes

Tags: calculus

> Find the equation of a plane perpendicular to each of the two planes $x - y + z = 0$ and $2x+y-4z-5=0$ and containing the point $(4, 0, -2)$.

Need help! Thank you. ^_^

Comment: How do you define perpendicularity (or angle in general) between two planes?

Comment: @gotit--thanks  I'm curious to know if there are more than one way to define perpendicularity between 2 planes. One definition I know of is "A plane C is perpendicular to a plane D if plane C contains a line that is perpendicular to plane D." Are there other common definitions that's not equivalent to this one?

Comment: Source: http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/geometry/fundamental-ideas/parallel-and-perpendicular-planes

Comment: @FreshAir One certainly *could* define any two subspaces as perpendicular if every vector in one were perpendicular to every vector in the other -- that is they'd each be subsets of the orthogonal complement of the other.  That's not the usual way of defining perpendicularity of planes, but one could define it that way.  Nevertheless I didn't ask OP the question because I didn't know the answer.  I asked so that OP might add it and any of his/her thoughts to the question.  Otherwise I thought this question should be closed -- and apparently I wasn't alone.

Answer (score 2):

Take cross product (outer product) of two normal vectors to find a vector that is normal to both planes.
$$(1,-1,1)\times(2,1,-4)=(3,6,3)$$
Therefore the plane equation is
$$x+2y+z=d$$
As it contains $(4,0,-2)$, $d=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation of plane be $ax+by+cz=1$

since the plane:$ax+by+cz=1$ is perpendicular to the plane: $x-y+z=0$ hence the product of normal vectors of the planes will be zero as follows $$(a, b, c)\cdot (1, -1, 1)=0$$
$$\implies a-b+c=0\tag 1$$
similarly, plane: $ax+by+cz=1$ is perpendicular to the plane: $2x+y-4z-5=0$ hence the product of normal vectors of the planes will be zero as follows $$(a, b, c)\cdot (2, 1, -4)=0$$
$$\implies 2a+b-4c=0\tag 2$$
Since, the plane: $ax+by+cz=1$ contains the point $(4, 0, -2)$ hence satisfying the equation of plane  as follows 
$$a(4)+b(0)+c(-2)=1$$ $$\implies 4a-2c=1\tag 3$$
Now, solving (1), (2) & (3), one should get 
$$a=\frac{1}{2}, \ \ b=1, \ \ c=\frac{1}{2} $$
hence, substituting the values of $a, b$ & $c$, the equation of the unknown plane is 
$$\color{red}{x+2y+z-2=0}$$